# Does $A$ and $A^TA$ have the same eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Do matrices $A$ and $A^TA$ have the same eigenvalues?

I think they do but I can't find anything online about it

Comment: Try a one by one matrix.

Comment: What if the matrix is bigger than 1x1?

Comment: Try it with $A=\begin{pmatrix}2&0&\ldots&0\\0&2&\ldots&0\\ \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\ 0&0&\ldots&2\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Probably your original question is : Do $A^2$ and $A^T A$ have same eigenvalues ?          

Which  the answer still is  "NO" .

Comment: Eigenvalues of $A^T A$ are nonnegative as the matrix $A^T A$ is nonnegative definite, whereas there is no restriction on the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: What's true is that $AA^T$ and $A^TA$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues, which are the squares of the singular values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\bf A$ with eigenvector $\bf x$, we have  $\mathbf{Ax}=\lambda\bf x$

Then, $(\mathbf{A^\top A})\mathbf x=\mathbf A^\top(\lambda \mathbf x)=(\lambda \mathbf A^\top)\bf x$

If $\bf A$ is symmetric, the above reduces to $(\mathbf{A^\top A})\mathbf x=\lambda^2\bf x$

So your claim is only true when $\mathbf A=\mathbf I$ $\quad($which implies $\lambda=1)$.

Comment: It would be helpful if people point out my mistakes besides downvoting.

Comment: I think you need to modify your last statement, since $x$ could be in the null space of $A$, and the eigenvalue could be 0.  I would also add the explanation that (I think) your point is that it is not true in general that $A^T A$ and $A$ have the same eigenvalues, since that can only be true for symmetric matrices if their eigenvalues are only 0 or 1.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't true in general. For example, if $A$ is symmetric, then if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $A$, then $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue for $A^TA = A^2$, which will not usually be an eigenvalue for $A$.

As a concrete example, let $A = \begin{bmatrix} 2\,\,\,0 \\0\,\,\,3\end{bmatrix}$. This matrix has eigenvalues $2$ and $3$. However, $A^TA = $$\begin{bmatrix} 4\,\,\,0 \\0\,\,\,9\end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $4$ and $9$.

Answer (score 0):

I think they don't have the same eigen values. For the matrix $A=2I$, $A$ has 2 as eigenvalue (multiple eigenvalue), and $A^tA = 4I$ has 4 as eigenvalue.